# Heat Equation with Antiperiodic BCs

Tags: fourier-series, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

Suppose I want to solve $u_{xx}=u_t$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ with initial condition $u_0(x),x\in[0,2\pi]$ at $t=0$. I am interested in an informal discussion first (i.e. writing dwon a solution etc.) for the boundary conditions:
$$
u(0,t)=-u(2\pi,t),\quad u_x(0,t)=u_x(2\pi,t).
$$
Obviously if the minus sign wasn't present then this can be studied via Fourier series but can a similar method be applied to this 'antiperiodic' case?

Has this been studied in the literature?

Comment: It might help to shift the domain to be centered at zero.

Comment: Have you tried the usual procedure of assuming a separable solution $F(x)G(t)$ and seeing where it takes you? Usually you get $F''(x) = \lambda F(x)$ and you end up rejecting all $\lambda \ge 0$ and require integer $\lambda = -k^2$ for boundary conditions. You might well get a solution for $\lambda = 0$ in this case and have more restrictions on the negative $\lambda$ case than usual.

Comment: Yes, but it is not clear to me that the system is complete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, there is not enough information to reduce this to a discrete eigenvalue problem. Separating variables $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ gives a linear ODE for $X$ of the form $X''/X = -k^2$ (the other one being $T'/T=-k^2$). This has solutions of the form $A\cos{(k(x-\pi)-a)}$, and we find that all we need to satisfy both boundary conditions is $\cos{a}=0$, so any function of the form $A\cos{(k(x-\pi)-\pi/2)}$ will work, for any value of $k$, real or complex (the $k=0$ solution may be found by dividing by $k$ and taking the limit as $k \to 0$, which gives $A(x-\pi)$, unsurprisingly).

Another way of looking at it is to consider a solution of the form $A\cos{kx}+B\sin{kx}$. We find that the boundary conditions reduce to one equation, $A\cos{k\pi}+B\sin{k\pi}=0$, so any $A,B,k$ satisfying this will work.

Comment: I think that is the general idea (short of some simple algebra corrections). Solution should be $A\sin(kx)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ say. $k$ can be arbitrary. This implies instability by looking at $\sinh$ solutions. But do we still have uniqueness in some sense/is there another way?

Comment: I think most people would be sufficiently bothered by the ill-posedness to not look further. I suspect you won't have uniqueness either, since you have enough functions to expand one in terms of a complete set of others that are orthonormal, and thus you could construct a nonzero solution to a zero initial condition by taking the difference. It might be worth asking a separate question about that problem specifically.